# Drawing canvas with mouse and iPad touch panel

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I started studying canvas and ran into a problem, drawing with the help of the canvas with the mouse onmousedown, onmousemove, onmouseup works and for the touchpanel the iPad used touchstart, touchmove, touchend however the code for the touchpanel does not work. I commented out the non-working code, I will be grateful for the help and guidance of the true path.

The code for drawing canvas in ipad does not work
     canvas.ontouchstart,canvas.touchstart,canvas.touchmove,canvas.touchend

```
 function unit(){
        canvasOffset = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        ctx.lineJoin = "round";
        canvas.onmousedown = function(e) {
            drawing = true;
            ctx.beginPath();
        }
        //canvas.ontouchstart = function(e) {
        //  if (e.touches) e = e.touches[0];
        //  return false;
        //}
        //canvas.touchstart = function(e) {
        //      drawing = true;
        //      ctx.beginPath();
        //}
        canvas.onmousemove = function(e) {
            if (drawing) {
                var mousePosition = getMousePosition(e);
              ctx.lineTo(mousePosition[0], mousePosition[1]);
                        myColor =      document.getElementById('myColor').style.background;
                        ctx.strokeStyle = myColor;
                ctx.stroke();
            }
        };
        //canvas.touchmove = function(e) {
        //      if (drawing) {
        //              var mousePosition = getMousePosition(e);
        //              ctx.lineTo(mousePosition[0], mousePosition[1]);
        //              myColor = document.getElementById('myColor').style.background;
        //              ctx.strokeStyle = myColor;
        //              ctx.stroke();
        //      }
        //};
        canvas.onmouseup = function(e) {
            drawing = false;
            ctx.closePath();
        }
        //canvas.touchend = function(e) {
        //      drawing = false;
        //      ctx.closePath();
        //}
        function getMousePosition(mouseEvent) {
            return [Math.floor(event.offsetX), Math.floor(event.offsetY)];
        }
}
```

Comment: What does 'Doesn't work' mean? What exactly does not work?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the problem.

Comment: The code for drawing canvas in ipad does not work (canvas.ontouchstart,canvas.touchstart,canvas.touchmove,canvas.touchend) I commented this code